# Help with Formatting + Lots of Errors

Tags: errors, formatting

I was typing up a small document of a few equations, and it was really messy trying to get what I wanted. I tried cleaning it up using the gather environment, but I don't know how to properly use it as you see below. I've attached the code and an image of what it produces (is there a good way to show this image in TEX Stack Exchange?). Secondly, a minor thing, but some of my sums have the subscript and superscript to the right of the Sum, and others are above and below, respectively. I would like to make them all above and below for all the equations. How would I go about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\[
p_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{ij}}
\]
\[
E_i=-\frac{\sum^n_{j=1} p_{ij} \cdot \ln p_{ij}}{\ln n}
\]
\[
w_i=\frac{1-E_i}{\sum^m_{i=1} (1-E_i)}
\]
\[
\overline{x}_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum^n_{j=1} x^2_{ij}}}
\]
\[
V_{ij}=\overline{x}_{ij}\cdot w_{i}
\]
\[
S^{+}_{j}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\left(V_{ij}-V^{+}_i\right)^2\right]^{0.5}
\]
\[
S^{-}_{j}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\left(V_{ij}-V^{-}_i\right)^2\right]^{0.5}
\]
\[
R_j=\frac{S_j^{-}}{S^{+}_j+S^{-}_{j}}
\]

VERSUS

\begin{gather}
p_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{ij}}
\\
E_i=-\frac{\sum^n_{j=1} p_{ij} \cdot \ln p_{ij}}{\ln n}
\\
w_i=\frac{1-E_i}{\sum^m_{i=1} (1-E_i)}
\\
\overline{x}_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum^n_{j=1} x^2_{ij}}}
\\
V_{ij}=\overline{x}_{ij}\cdot w_{i}
\\
S^{+}_{j}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\left(V_{ij}-V^{+}_i\right)^2\right]^{0.5}
\\
S^{-}_{j}=\left[\sum_{i=1}^m\left(V_{ij}-V^{-}_i\right)^2\right]^{0.5}
\\
R_j=\frac{S_j^{-}}{S^{+}_j+S^{-}_{j}}
\\
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: $$ vs $ puts the limits above and below---different formatting, but it looks like what you're going for. Most folks are okay with limits on the side.

Comment: what is your goal exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to get first get rid of all the \[ \] notatin because it's super repetitive. So essentially create the same image without the \[ \]. And when I try to use gather it doesn't work as you see above. It also doesn't italicize the "p" right under the "VERSUS" which I don't understand as well. How would I be able to change the formatting of the SUM?

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at the summation terms that occur in the `\frac` expressions in the first four equations, you'll notice two things. First, the upper and lower limits are typeset to the right of rather than above and below the summation symbols; that's the feature you've pointed out. Second, the summation symbols are smaller than, say, those in equations 6 and 7.

This isn't accidental; in fact, it is *deliberate*. TeX has four basic math "styles": `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`. The default math typesetting rules that TeX incorporates specify, for `\displaystyle` settings, "large" math operators (such as `\sum` and `\prod`) *and* placing any limits of summation/multiplication above and below the symbol. (There are separate rules for `\int`, i.e., integral expressions.) For `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`, respectively, TeX uses progressively smaller symbols *and* places the limits of summation, multiplication etc to the right of they symbol. The following screenshot shows the same expression, three times: First in `\displaystyle`, next in `\textstyle`, and finally in `\scriptstyle`.

[image]

Another math typesetting rule that TeX employs pertains to the processing of the contents of the numerator and denominator of a `\frac` expression. If the `\frac` expression occurs while TeX is in `\displaystyle` mode (as is the case in a `gather` environment), the numerator is processed in `\textstyle`, while the denominator is processed in cramped `\textstyle`.

The joint application of these rules explains why the sizes of the summation symbols aren't all the same across the equations *and* why the limits of summation are sometimes set above and below the symbol and sometimes to the right of it.

As noted earlier, this is all quite deliberate and, dare I say it, has stood the test of fine math typesetting scrutiny.

If you decide that you simply must have the numerators and denominators of `\frac` expressions typeset in `\displaystyle`, you can do so easily by defining a macro called `\ddfrac` as follows

```
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
```

("ddfrac" is short for "double-displaystyle frac", I suppose) and replacing the `\frac` directives in equations 1 to 4 with `\ddfrac` instructions. Be forewarned, though, that the outcome will likely not be better -- in fact, it'll likely be far worse -- than what's produced by sticking with the default rules. E.g., the blind use of `\ddfrac` in the right-hand column in the following screenshot appears to be crassly profligate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sumlimits]{amsmath}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\begin{document}
\addtolength\jot{1ex}

$
\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \quad\text{versus}\quad 
\textstyle    \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \quad\text{versus}\quad
\scriptstyle  \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}
$

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
p_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{ij}} \\
E_i=-\frac{\sum^n_{j=1} p_{ij} \cdot \ln p_{ij}}{\ln n} \\
w_i=\frac{1-E_i}{\sum^m_{i=1} (1-E_i)} \\
\overline{x}_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum^n_{j=1} x^2_{ij}}}
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}
VERSUS
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
p_{ij}=\ddfrac{x_{ij}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_{ij}} \\
E_i=-\ddfrac{\sum^n_{j=1} p_{ij} \cdot \ln p_{ij}}{\ln n} \\
w_i=\ddfrac{1-E_i}{\sum^m_{i=1} (1-E_i)} \\
\overline{x}_{ij}=\ddfrac{x_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum^n_{j=1} x^2_{ij}}}
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)